# How to use .innerText to find sum in a function?

Tags: javascript, button

Here's what I have for context.
This code is defining a function to calculate all the totals I would need.

```
function getTotals() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").nodeValue;

    var subTotal = input1 + input2 + input3 + input4 + input5;
    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerText = subTotal;

    var total = (subTotal * 0.08875) + subTotal;
    document.getElementById("total").innerText = total;

    var item1 = document.getElementById("item-input1").nodeValue; 

    var itemTotal = item1 + item2 + item3 + item4 + item5;
    document.getElementById("total-items").innerText = itemTotal;
}

        <div class="calculate">
            <button id="calculate-btn" type="button">
                Calculate
            </button> 
        </div>

        <div class="subtotal" id="subtotal" onclick="getTotals()">
            <p>Total before tax:</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: When I press the button to calculate it doesn't work and I get a bunch of 0's in all the places where it should have calculated the total

Comment: Can you add button from yout html too?

Comment: <div class="calculate">
            <button id="calculate-btn" type="button">
                Calculate
            </button> 
        </div>

        <div class="subtotal" id="subtotal" onclick="getTotals()">
            <p>Total before tax:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="total" id="total" onclick="getTotals()">
            <p>Total after tax:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="total-items" id="total-items" onclick="getTotals()">
            <p>Total items:</p>
        </div>

Comment: It would be better if you explain what you are trying to do and what you want to do and what trouble you are having in doing it. Also, if you have to add any extra info, add it to the original question with proper formatting. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi, I can't add everything otherwise Stack would be upset with me for only submitting code. What I am doing is creating a shopping list. I have predetermined 5 input fields for the user to type in the item and item price. What I then want is for when the user clicks the button it will calculate the subtotal, total, and list all the items they inputted into the system. So right now the button doesn't yield any results when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things that I would suggest. First is that if you are trying to add numbers together from an input, you should parse from a string to the value type you want.
Example:

```
var input1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input1").value);
```

But the bigger issue is probably that you are using .nodeValue rather than .value. This is what [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodevalue.asp) has to say about it:
"If the node is an element node, the nodeValue property will return null."

Answer (score 0):

`nodeValue` returns `string` 
[nodeValue docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)
You can try to do `console.log(typeof item1)`
The `+` operator does string concatenation when you are adding two string together so you add string '123' to string '456' you get '123456'

To actually sum numbers in your example you need numbers istead of string.
You can use `Number()` or just put + in front of the string +'25' === 25

[Number() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly "fancy" way to do it, selecting the inputs by class instead of id,
and looping through them with `Array.reduce` to calculate the subtotal.

**Note that:**
  - input elements store their contents in the **`value`** property
  - setting an element's text content can be done with the **`textContent`** property

**Here's how the Array.reduce method works**  (Learn more [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))
  It can take two arguments: 1) a function, and 2) a starting value.
  Reduce **calls the function for each item** in the array.
  Each time, it gives the function two arguments:
    - **an accumulated value** (called `runningTotal` in the demo)
    - **the current item** in the array (called `currentInput` in the demo)
  Each time, the function **returns the accumulated value** (like `runningTotal`.)

(The very first time `reduce` calls the function, there is no runningTotal yet,
  so we can provide a starting value for it to use instead.)
  After the very last time, reduce gives us back the function's returned runningTotal.

**And here's the demo code:**

```js
// We define HTML element selectors once at the start, instead of on each click
//(`getElementsByClassName` gets an HTMLCollection; `Array.from` makes it an Array)
const inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("addend"));
const subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
const total = document.getElementById("total");

function getTotals() {

  // When `reduce` is done, the final `runningTotal` will be stored in `subtot`
  const subtot = inputs.reduce(

    // This function is the first argument to the reduce method
    function(runningTotal, currentInput){

      // For each input, its value will be added to the previous running total
      // (HTML only stores strings; `parseFloat` tries to make a number)
      let newRunningTotal = runningTotal + parseFloat(currentInput.value);
      return newRunningTotal;
    },

    // This value is the second argument to the reduce method
    0
  );

  // Now that `reduce` has gotten the final number in`subtot`, we can use it
  subtotal.textContent = subtot;
  total.textContent = subtot * 1.08875;
}
```

```html
<input class="addend" />
<input class="addend" />
<div id="subtotal"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
<button onclick="getTotals()">Calculate</button>
```